# Wi-Fi Access point on a Debian

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, debian

I am trying to setup a Wi-Fi Access Point on this machine:

```
$ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.14.79-v7+ #1159 SMP Sun Nov 4 17:50:20 GMT 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux
$ cat /etc/issue
Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 \n \l
```

I have followed many tutorials, but my device never publish its SSID and therefore I cannot establish a connection.

How to debug my configuration?

What I configured is:

1. Add static IP for `wlan0` in `/etc/dhcpd.conf`
2. Configure a DHCP server on `wlan0` in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`
3. Configure hostapd in `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`
4. Bind `hostapd` in `/etc/default/hostapd`
5. Start the services `hostapd`, `dnsmasq`

And some status:

```
$ iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=31 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

$ sudo ifconfig wlan0
wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.4.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.4.255
        ether b8:27:eb:d5:30:24  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

$ sudo systemctl status hostapd
? hostapd.service - LSB: Advanced IEEE 802.11 management daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/hostapd; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2019-02-27 13:58:13 CET; 1h 2min ago

$ sudo systemctl status dnsmasq.service
? dnsmasq.service - dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-02-27 13:34:39 CET; 1h 26min ago
```

What could be my issue?

Comment: Exclude comments from your `hostapd.conf` and post it.

Comment: Also "Mode:Managed" suggests that hostapd doesn't have exclusive access to wlan0, and something else is using it as client/station instead of AP.